# Restricted Timestamp cell needed in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp

I am new to google scripts and need some help getting my spreadsheet to do what I need it to. Here's what the spreadsheet looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Anu.png)

Here's what I would like to have happen.
1. When "Appointment" is entered into a cell in column B, the corresponding cell in column E automatically has the current date entered.
2. When the same cell has "Proposals" entered into it, the corresponding cell in column F automatically has the current date entered.
3. When the same cell is changed to "Closed," the corresponding cell in column G has the current date entered.
4. And finally, if the same cell is changed to "Lost," the corresponding cell in column H automatically has the current date entered.

Any help that someone can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you having issues with code you've written? If so, can you share it? If not, please see [StackOverflow Help/FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is curious, I did find something that works for me:

```
 function onEdit() {
   var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
     if( r.getColumn() == 2, r.getValue()==='Appointment' ) {
       var nextCell = r.offset(0, 5);//offset (row,column)
       if( nextCell.getValue() === '')//checks for blank cell
       nextCell.setValue(new Date());}
     else if( r.getColumn() == 2, r.getValue()==='Proposals' ) {
       var nextCell = r.offset(0, 6);//offset (row,column)
       if( nextCell.getValue() === '')//checks for blank cell
       nextCell.setValue(new Date());}
     else if( r.getColumn() == 2, r.getValue()==='Closed' ) {
       var nextCell = r.offset(0, 7);//offset (row,column)
       if( nextCell.getValue() === '')//checks for blank cell
       nextCell.setValue(new Date());}
     else if( r.getColumn() == 2, r.getValue()==='Lost' ) {
       var nextCell = r.offset(0, 8);//offset (row,column)
       var closedCell = r.offset(0, 7);
       if( nextCell.getValue() === '')//checks for blank cell
       nextCell.setValue(new Date()), closedCell.clearContent();}
       }
```